# Ansible file module throws a error when trying to recursively set ownership on files

Tags: ruby, rvm, ansible

The task is

```
- name: ensure rvm install path is writable by the set owner:group
  file: path='{{ rvm1_install_path }}' state=directory recurse=yes owner='{{ rvm1_user }}' group='{{ rvm1_group }}'
```

And I get

```
TASK: [rvm_io.rvm1-ruby | ensure rvm install path is writable by the set owner:group] ***
failed: [54.68.205.15] => {"failed": true, "gid": 111, "group": "jenkins", "item": "", "mode": "0755", "owner": "jenkins", "path": "/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 106}
msg: chgrp failed

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

The folders exist already.

I am using

```
sudo: true
sudo_user: jenkins
```

Since my ssh user is `ubuntu`.

This is part of [my issue with the ansible role provided by rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible/issues/8), but it feels like this might not be too closely related to RVM.. hence im asking here, but not sure.

Comment: Question rendered redundant by changes in the ansible role to not use `chown` at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `jenkins` user doesn't have permission to create the directory or set permissions. Further, if any files/directories exist and are owned by someone other than jenkins, the jenkins user won't be able to chown them.

That's why `chgrp` fails. You need superuser permissions, and hopefully the jenkins user is very limited in permissions.

This is probably what you intended:

```
- name: ensure rvm path exists
  file: path='{{ rvm1_install_path }}' state=directory recurse=yes owner='{{ rvm1_user }}' group='{{ rvm1_group }}'
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
- name: all rvm files should be owned by our user
  file: path='{{ rvm1_install_path }}' recurse=yes owner='{{ rvm1_user }}' group='{{ rvm1_group }}'
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
```

Comment: The folders are owned by `jenkins`, as far as I can see, after the failure, the ownership and permissions are ok regardless..

Comment: `rvm1_install_path` is `~/.rvm`, in the jenkins home folder

Comment: @karthik-t your problem lies with sudoing to a nonroot user. Period.